# How to map a OneDrive Folder -> to a Teams File Folder

Tags: office365, onedrive, microsoft-teams, collaboration, microsoft-onedrive

Situation:

I have a shared OneDrive Folder with Project Files in it:

[image]

want to be able to map this folder to a Teams Channel File Folder

[image]

Goal is to be able to edit files in OneDrive by accessing them in Teams

Maybe this isn't possible and I should just host everything in Teams, but it would be helpful if I could just map it from OneDrive To Teams, as our org has recently put all our files into OneDrive.

If this isn't possible, best practices for managing this would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the opposite direction (where the files are stored in Teams), by linking a Teams folder into your OneDrive:

[image]

And it shows up as a folder in OneDrive that you can work on and organize directly through OneDrive. It adds a handy link to the Team as well:

[image]

---

Shared OneDrive folders do show up in Teams under **Files** (on the left) > **Shared** > **With you** > filter by Folder:

[image]

---

But a specific Team/Channel cannot natively link to folders stored in OneDrive outside of using the OneDrive share invite URLs

Comment: Thank you @Cpt.Whale !